# How do I show one scene after anothe in javaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I first want to show a splash scene in the beginning of my application, then go to my main menu scene, but whatever i do only one of them is shown, i tried like this:

```
if (change == false) {
    mainController.start(this.windowStage);
    this.windowStage.show();
    change = true;
}
if (change == true) {
    mainController.startMenu(this.windowStage);
    this.windowStage.show();
}
```

but only the main menu is shown. My controller class:

```
public class MainController {
    public void start(Stage windowStage) {
        Scene splashScreen = SplashScreen.getScene(windowStage.getWidth(), windowStage.getHeight(), windowStage);
        windowStage.setScene(splashScreen);
    }
    public void startMenu(Stage windowStage){
        try {
            MainMenu menu = new MainMenu();
            Scene menuShow = menu.MainMenu();
            windowStage.setScene(menuShow);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is executed in order, one statement after the other. So you basically show the splash screen, then *immediately* replace it with the "menu" screen. So you never see the splash screen. What are you actually trying to do? Usually a splash screen is shown while some long-running initialization process is happening. Unless you can show us something similar to the real use-case, there is not much anyone has to work with to help you out.

Comment: Instead of trying to make your own splashscreen you may want to use a Preloader. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm

Comment: maybe thread.sleep(splashScreenTimeOut)